# Can I use pycharm community or vscode at work in company?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pycharm

I am working on a telecom company. Can I use vscode, or pycharm to develop our product at work totally freely? Is there any restriction or obligation?

thanks.

Comment: Maybe search on google? Here https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2017/09/pycharm-community-edition-and-professional-edition-explained-licenses-and-more/ there's exactly that question answered. While here https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/FAQ#_is-vs-code-free is the answer for VS Code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am currently using `vs-code` at my work and it is costing me nothing (I also have no restrictions). I have also used `Pycharm`, but you only get 30-days free, and then you have to pay. You can however use the community version for free if you'd like.

You can use any of the two in a company environment. My personal preference is `vs-code` though.